# What is the $k^{al}$-points of a variety over $k$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, schemes, abelian-varieties

Let $X=\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-x-1))$. So $X$  is an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ given by function $y^2=x^3+x+1$.

Now I wonder what is meaning of a $\mathbb{C}$ points of  $X$? I think there are two explanations.

Firstly, it can refer a of map $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C})\to X$.

Secondly, it also may refer  a solution of $y^2=x^3+x+1$ in $\mathbb{C}$ such as $(-1,i)$.

I think these two explanations are not equivalent. So what is the definition of a $\mathbb{C}$-point of $X$?

More generally, let $k$ be a field, $k^{'}$ is an field extension of $k$, $X$ is a variety over $k$, $X_{k^{'}}$ is the base change of $X$. If we choose second explanations as our definition, then it seems that the $k^{'}$ points of $X$ are rational points of $X_{k^{'}}$. Am I right?

Thank you very much if you can help me.

Comment: Your "more generally" statement is correct (except to be perfectly clear you may want to say "the $k'$ points of $X$ are the $k'$-rational points of $X_{k'}$). The statements from "firstly" and "secondly" are equivalent when taken in the right context - why do you think they're inequivalent? (It may be that you aren't working in the correct context for them to be equivalent, but giving a good explanation will be easier if you can give more specific details about the issue you're having.)

Comment: You are totally correct. I made a mistake.   These two explanations are equivalent. Thank you very very much!!

Answer (score 1):

There is a bit of notation nightmare, the point is to get the few concepts.

For a prime ideal $I\subset k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ and $X=V(I)\subset \Bbb{A}^n_k$ and a field $L\supset k$ then $X(L)=\{ a\in L^n,\forall f\in I, f(a)=0\}$. This is a set. The variety is $X$ which is $X(\overline{k})$ endowed with a topological space structure, a Galois action, plus (more important) its ring of regular functions $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I$ (whose ideals define the open/closed sets of $X(\overline{k})$).

If $I$ is not a prime ideal then $X$ is an algebraic set and the same objects come with it.

The based change is to look at the ideal $I_L= I\ L[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ (with the prime ideal $I=(x^2+1)\subset \Bbb{Q}[x]$ then $I_\Bbb{C}$ is not a prime ideal anymore) from which we have the algebraic set $X_L=V(I_L)\subset \Bbb{A}^n_L$ which gives again some sets $X_L(E)$ for any field $E\supset L$.

When $I$ is prime and $L=\overline{k}$ or when $L/k$ is Galois it is interesting to look at the action of $Gal(L/k)$ on $X(L)$ and $X_L$ and how it permutes the irreducible components of the latter (equivalently the embeddings of $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I$ into $L[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I_L$). For $L/k$ Galois then $X(k)$ is the subset of $X(L)$ fixed by $Gal(L/k)$.

Comment: So, you think that a $L$ point of $X$ is just the rational point of $X_{L}$? But how to explain the $L$ point of a scheme $X$? I think that a $L$ point of a scheme is a map from the $\mathrm{Spec}(L) \to X$. That is a point of $X$ with residue field $L$.

Comment: For $L/k$ a finite extension the Galois orbit of some $a\in X(L)$ corresponds to a maximal ideal of $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I$ and its residue field is a subfield $F$ of the normal closure of $L/k$, then $F = k(\{a^\sigma\})$ (the extension generated by the coordinates of the conjugates of $a$). The scheme stuff is to generalize this to things like $Spec(\Bbb{Z}[x]/(x^2))$

Comment: The word point is ambiguous : does it refer to $a$ or its Galois orbit or to the maximal ideal of the ring ? The base change clearly changes something in each of those.

Comment: It seems $X(L)$ is the same with $X_{L}(L)$ since they are both the solutions of $f$ in $L$?

Comment: Sorry I meant $F\cong k(a^\sigma)\cong k(a)$

Comment: I have edited my question a lot and I think it is more clearly now. Could you see my question again? Thank you very much.